# Нужна помощь с .htaccess и 301 редиректом

Tags: php, yii2, .htaccess

Перенес сайт на новый движок, Yii2 basic.
От предыдущих урл пришлось отказаться.
Пытаюсь настроить .htaccess, но ничего не помогает, настраиваю .htaccess который находится в корне сайта.
sait.ru/news/new.php?id=100 - то что было
sait.ru/news/100/ - то что необходимо
Помогите пожалуйста

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !htaccess=Y
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9])$
RewriteRule ^news/new\.php$ /news/%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule . index.php
```

это мой .htaccess, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конфигурационном файле указанно `'showScriptName' => false` ?

```
'components' => [
// ...
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    // Hide index.php
    'showScriptName' => false,
    // Use pretty URLs
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'rules' => [
    ],
],
// ...
```

],

Вообще странно, что Вы решили делать все это через .htaccess. Это решается средсвами самого Yii2 
Тоесть сам .htaccess должен быть прост:

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

urlManager должен быть настроен как я написал выше, и указать в правилах след. строку:

```
'rules' => [
   'news' => 'news/index', // список всех новостей
   'news/<id:\d+>' => 'news/new', // перенаправит в action new контроллера news с id = NNN 
]
```

Comment: Да, именно так...

Comment: Я расширил ответ. Посмотрите

Comment: Я попробовал способом из расширенного ответа, не работает(.
Я думаю потому что я проект сделал извращенным методом, ибо перехожу со своей самописки в yii(параллельно изучая). "news" - action в контроллере "site", а ссылка "sait.ru/news/new.php?id=100"(со старого сайта)

Comment: если news - это action в контроллере site тогда надо в правилах прописать rules по другому: 
    'rules' => [
   'news/<id:\d+>' => 'site/news', // вызов actionNews($id) в SiteController.php и подстановка $id с нужным номером новости 
]

Comment: у меня уже так и работает, а так же в rules это правило уже прописано, просто я хочу чтобы с поисковика люди приходили с
sait.ru/news/new.php?id=100 на sait.ru/news/100/

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /news/%1/? [L,R=301]
```